# OC4J to Weblogic migration steps

Tags: java, migration, weblogic, oc4j

I need to deploy my ear file in weblogic server. The ear is currently deployed in OC4J . What are all the config changes i need to make in order to achieve this. I have a web module and ear module packaged in my ear file . Please help.

Comment: This question is really broad - have you tried to deploy the ear file in weblogic? What errors have you seen?

Answer (score 1):

Common steps are

1. To change oc4j specific config file to weblogic file

   - orion-web.xml to weblogic.xml
   - orion-ejb-jar.xml to weblogic-ejb-jar.xml
   - orion-application.xml to weblogic-application.xml
2. Change build.xml file to include these files according to the weblogic defined ear structure
3. Click [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/programming/environment.html) for ear structure